# KDB/Q splayed table column type changing from 0h to 77h

Tags: kdb

I have a table that has some columns of type 0h with normal strings in them. Meta shows type C.

I am saving this table to a splayed DB with

```
.Q.dpft[hsym `$path; dt;`sym;`t]]
```

However when I load the splayed table later

```
\l path_to_my_table
```

the type of all 0h columns changes to 77h. How can I avoid that?
I am using 3.6

Comment: Is there a reason you want to avoid type 77h? This corresponds to anymap files, which were introduced in 3.6 to improve performance via memory mapping. I have some information on it at https://kx.com/blog/memory-mapping-in-kdb/ if you are interested

Comment: yes, I would like to avoid it. reason is that some functions that take the type into consideration and break on that type as they have not been updated. And the libs probably won't be updated any time soon, so my quickest way to dodge this is to avoid 77h

Comment: Also, I am a bit confused, because I have similar splayed DBs that don't do that and I can't see any difference in the raw data or the way it is generated. always via Q.dpft

Comment: I don't think you can. Forgetting about .Q.dpft, writing a list of strings to disk (with either set or 1:), results in type 77h. Can't really simplify further than set. If you have upgraded to anymap (3.6) I think you need to modify your code to handle it (check for 77h). For your example that doesn't involve type 77h (assuming it was written with same kdb version?), does it contain any compound columns?

Comment: Agree with Adam - if you made a conscious effort to upgrade your kdb version to v3.6 then it should have been a planned task involving many parts (updating all database readers/writers to v3.6, updating code to handle the new anymap type 77h etc). If you can't do this then you might consider rolling back your data writers to version 3.5 where you won't have the type 77h issue, but such a rollback will itself require some planning as data written in v3.6 won't be readable from v3.5 etc

Comment: Ok, thanks for the comments. At least now I know the way to go is to get the code updated to properly handle this.

Answer (score 0):

As a means of giving you a means to answer the question and decide engineering tradeoffs - not because I believe introducing new code for this is the best way to go about it - you might consider how this is avoided when writing to TP logs (-11! cannot stream from anymap files).

This was a consideration in some of our test code when my team looked at this upgrade in 2019, and we wrote a generic routine to take a list of input and manually write it to a TP log format. Repurposing for your use, it would be something like:

```
f:get`:file
h:hopen hdel`:file
h f
hclose h
```